# Cross Domain Conversion Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

**SETUP:**
Having a few different information sites/domains about my products and one single site/domain shop-site where you the purchase, checkout and so on happens, I'm having troubles to find a proper solution for a comprehensive tracking of all the pages including the conversion tracking.

**IDEAL:** 
What I want is to get reports seperated for each site (shop-site as well as information-sites), but add some conversion tracking. Ideal would be to be able to track a conversion when the user gets to the checkout process, so that I can see it in the statistics of the shop-site as well as on the site that referred to this sale/conversion and maybe even a funnel visualisation for the whole action.

**WHAT I ALREADY GOT:**
I already set up statistics for each site/domain. I do have set events for a referal to the shop-site as well as an event when the user checks out.

**WHAT I TRIED:** 
I set up cross domain tracking for one of my information-sites and the shop-site, so now the events show up in that single property.

Unfortunately thats not the statistic I intend to get, as the whole data got consolidated from those 2 properties. Also it made the tracking goal/conversion only accessible for that single property, while I can't distinguish between a conversion made originally from this site or one of the others.

Is it possible to achieve what I actually intend to do or what's the proper way to track such a setup??

Answer (score 2):

You can either use an additional tracker (so you have one UA id that goes in your "normal" domain, one  that goes in your shpooing site and one that is placed on both sites) - you'd still have both pages tracked in separate properties, but you'd have one rollup property that tracks all your sites. This might however unwanted complexity if you use event tracking etc (since you'd have to see to it that events are always pushed to the correct tracker).

An easier solutions is via views/profiles - use the same UA id for both sites; create views based on domain name (filter in the admin section) to track each site separately; for the common data view that display data from both sites create a [filter that includes the hostname](http://www.annielytics.com/how-to-add-a-hostname-filter-in-ga/) in the reports so you can tell both sites apart in the report.